# SWRevealViewController rightRevealToggle not working with UIButton in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, storyboard, swrevealviewcontroller

In my xcode project, I want a UIButton to open a right slide-out menu using SWRevealViewController but it isn't working. Any help?

He's the code in my view didLoad for the UIButton:

```
SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    if ( revealViewController )
    {
    [sidebarButton addTarget:revealViewController action:@selector(rightRevealToggle:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];
    }
```

And here is the IBAction for the button:

```
- (IBAction)reveal:(id)sender {
    SWRevealViewController *revealViewController = self.revealViewController;
    [self revealViewController];
}
```

I am using storyboard in xcode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok, so I fixed the issue. In my storyboard file instead of "sw_rear" segue identifier I put "sw_right" and that was it.

Comment: how can I change the segue programmatically because my app is supporting Arabic And English so I need if it English side shows from left, and if it arabic shows from right